# sum middle number with jagged array in C#

Tags: c#

I write some code with jagged array but when i sum middle number program not working and i cant fix it...:

```
 public class JaggedArray
{ 
    public static void Array()
    {
        int[][] arrayOfArray = ArrayOfArray();
        var tong = 0;
        for (var i = 1; i < arrayOfArray.Length; i++)
        {
            for (var j = 0; j < arrayOfArray[i].Length; j++)
            {
                var bienTam = arrayOfArray[i].Length;
                var tamThoi = j;
                if (bienTam%2==0&&tamThoi==bienTam/2) 
                {
                    tamThoi++;
                    tong += arrayOfArray[i][tamThoi];
                }
            }
        }
        OutPut(arrayOfArray, tong);
    }

private static int[][] ArrayOfArray()
    {
        Random ngauNhien = new Random();
        int[][] arrayOfArray = new int[13][];
        for (var i = 0; i <arrayOfArray.Length; i++)
        {
            arrayOfArray[i] = new int[i];
            for (var j = 0; j < arrayOfArray[i].Length; j++)
            {
                arrayOfArray[i][j] = ngauNhien.Next(0, 99); //throw exception

            }
        }

        return arrayOfArray;
    }
```

can someone explain reason why i wrong and how ti fix it?

Comment: @CallumLinington i use loop to specified second array???

Comment: @CallumLinington [code] for (var i = 0; i <arrayOfArray.Length; i++)
        {
            arrayOfArray[i] = new int[i];

Comment: Your `tamThoi` value is not being checked that it is outside the bounds of the array. Secondly the `arrayOfArray[i] = new int[i]` that you mentioned is initialising a different sized array each time - is this desired?

Comment: I've got it compiling

Comment: the exception appears to occur on a different line than the one cited

Comment: on tong += arrayOfArray[i][tamThoi];

Comment: @CallumLinington Omg, Thank you alot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are solving is the one *Linq* is very good for:

```
int[][] arrayOfArray = new int[][] {
  new[] {1, 2, 3}, // 2 is the middle item
  new[] {4, 5}     // in case of tie, let 5 (right) be the middle item
  new[] {7},       // 7  
  new int[] {},    // should be ignored
};

// 2 + 5 + 7 == 14 
var result = arrayOfArray
  .Where(line => line != null && line.Length > 0)
  .Sum(line => line[line.Length / 2]);
```

Answer (score 0):

So I've got it compiling:

```
public class JaggedArray
{
    public static void Array()
    {
        int[][] arrayOfArray = ArrayOfArray();
        var tong = 0;
        for (var i = 1; i < arrayOfArray.Length; i++)
        {
            for (var j = 0; j < arrayOfArray[i].Length; j++)
            {
                var bienTam = arrayOfArray[i].Length;
                var tamThoi = j;
                if (j % 2 == 0 && j / 2 == bienTam / 2)
                {
                    tamThoi++;
                    // You need to check here that tamThoi isn't
                    // outside the bounds of your array
                    if (tamThoi >= arrayOfArray[i].Length)
                    {
                        continue;
                    }
                    tong += arrayOfArray[i][tamThoi];
                }
            }
        }


    }

    private static int[][] ArrayOfArray()
    {
        Random ngauNhien = new Random();
        int[][] arrayOfArray = new int[13][];
        for (var i = 0; i < 13; i++)
        {
            arrayOfArray[i] = new int[i];
            // here you're better off using i
            // instead of the arrayOfArray[i].Length - because you know the length
            for (var j = 0; j < i; j++)
            {
                arrayOfArray[i][j] = ngauNhien.Next(0, 99);
            }
        }

        return arrayOfArray;
    }
}
```

You can make this far more succinct with LINQ.

Comment: i edit like you but cant count sum of jagged array XD

Comment: resuit allway is 0 when i run this program

Comment: Do you need to put this line back `OutPut(arrayOfArray, tong);`